# what is the `send_keys` did in capybara

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, capybara

I have a problem: `what is the send_keys did in capybara ?`

I know that：

```
element.send_keys :enter
```

is to hit `enter`

but i found it can also enable us to upload file here([capybara can not find file input field to attach file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32986393/capybara-can-not-find-file-input-field-to-attach-file))

for example:

```
element.send_keys("/home/userA/Desktop/chivalry-medieval-warfare.jpg")
```

will upload `chivalry-medieval-warfare.jpg`

How can it do that? I totally didn't know the mechanism behind `send_keys`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`#send_keys` does what it says -- it sends keys via events to elements on the page  -  `element.send_keys([:ctrl, 'a'], 'hello')` would send ctrl-a followed by the keys h e l l o - which in an input field would normally select all the text and then replace it (platform dependent because of ctrl vs cmd/meta).  The fact that its uploading a file is a side effect of the way file inputs in selenium work and is not necessarily compatible across drivers and should not be depended on to work or even to keep working in selenium.  For uploading files you should use `#attach_file (after executing whatever css changes are required to make the actual file input visible if necessary)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It means that uploading a file is depending on the driver(selenium)? It may be not working on other drivers like poltergeist, webkit?

Comment: @timlentse - It means you should always use `#attach_file` to upload a file. Using `send_keys` does work to upload a file with selenium today but probably won't work with other drivers, and probably won't work with selenium either at some point in the next few versions of Capybara

Comment: Yeah i got it  and thanks a lot. I learn a lot from your answer.